# PayPal API certificate concept understanding

Tags: paypal

Its confusion rather than a technical problem. I have merchant account on Paypal , some time ago I developed a application, in which API certification authentication to integrate with Paypal.
Now i have develop a new application and want to attach with Paypal with same account. But in this application I have used express checkout API with API signature method. 
Now I have two doubts:

1. Is it possible to have both the type of aPI authentication.
2. A bit more lame question, how can I relate my merchant account with developer account ?

Comment: These questions seem better suited to your PayPal support, as it doesn't appear like you have a clear enough understanding for us to figure out what's going on. Real-time support would be better for working through such issues.

Comment: Yes I was mixing two problem in a question , making it unclear. I have sorted aout both the problem. API certificate was old authentication process now Paypal recommends using API signature. one cant have both scheme applied on single merchant account. For second question, I got a URL where i can generate my live API credential and can move to live system.  Thanks anyway for tolrating my stupid question calmly. :)